# How can I give the playing song path of any player?

Tags: c#, wmplib

How can I give the playing song path of any player?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace EliteMusic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsMediaPlayerClass player=new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
            MessageBox.Show(player.currentMedia.name);

        }
    }
}
```

I get this error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because currentMedia is not set (null). You have to specify a path first to play with the WindowsMediaPlayerClass.

Comment: thanks but i want get path of current song that playing in windows media player now. what is the solution?

Comment: Maybe you should look up some tutorials for this. What you are doing in your code above is creating a media player object to play the songs by yourself rather than getting an active instance from the windows media player.